# FTP: Connect as local user with different password

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I want give some people FTP access to the files of unix user `bob`. Since `bob` has sudo, I don't want to share his unix password.

How can I make sure FTP users have the same file rights as `bob` without giving his password?

---

*Note 1 : I currently use VSFTPD, but I'm happy with any CLI FTP server.*

*Note 2 : Ideally, I would like to setup an FTP-only password which connects as `bob`. Having a new user, say `alice`, with the same rights as `bob`, would be fine too, but I want any future file created by `bob` to be immediately read/writable by `alice` as well!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `alice` user into `bob`'s group,
since `bob` is the creator and owner of the files.

To check who is the owner of a file, use

```
$ ls -l filename
```

To see which groups `bob` is registered in, use

```
$ groups bob
```

To add existing user `alice` to a group, use

```
# usermod -a -G groupname alice
```

Also check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/) out, for more on user management.